# Clear Labels or Textbox on Panel or Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label, panel

I have dynamic Labels and TextBox's on one panel.
I can delete the Panel. No Problem but then I also don't know how to delete the Textboxes etc

[image]

and i hoped that i can refresh or clear the panel so that all labels and textboxes will deleted..

```
        Label makeLabelC = new Label();
        makeLabelC.Width = 100;
        makeLabelC.Font = new Font(makeLabelC.Font.Name, 8, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
        makeLabelC.Location = new Point(400, 100);
        makeLabelC.Name = e.Node.Text;
        makeLabelC.Text = e.Node.Text;
        this.Controls.Add(makeLabelC);
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);

        TextBox textboxC = new TextBox();
        textboxC.Width = 100;

        textboxC.Location = new Point(500, 100 );
        textboxC.Name = e.Node.Text + "lbl";
        textboxC.Text = "enter here";
        this.Controls.Add(textboxC);
        this.Controls.Add(panel1);


        for (int z = 0; z < n; z++)
        {
            Label makeLabel = new Label();
            makeLabel.Width = 100;
            makeLabel.Location = new Point(400, 150 + 2 * z * makeLabel.Height);
            makeLabel.Name = e.Node.Text;
            makeLabel.Text = e.Node.Nodes[z].Text;
            this.Controls.Add(makeLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(panel1);

            TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
            textbox.Width = 100;
            textbox.Location = new Point(500, 150 + 2 * z * textbox.Height);
            textbox.Name = e.Node.Text + "lbl";
            textbox.Text = "enter here";
            this.Controls.Add(textbox);
            this.Controls.Add(panel1);


        }

    }
```

is there a way with panel how to do this or an other solution?
I thought that the Panel can help me there...

thanks Janik

Comment: If you remove a panel then its sub controls are also removed, are you sure the controls are on the panel?

Comment: yes I add with 'this.Controls.Add(textbox)'. And how to remove the panel and create it with same properties and and ?

Comment: `this` sounds likes its the form. Please add the code where you add the panel and controls (to your question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the controls to the form instead of the panel - which you also add multiple times

```
this.Controls.Add(panel1); // do this once
panel1.Controls.Add(textbox); // add the controls to the panel
```

Once you have done this, when you remove the panel, you will also remove its child controls.